# bazel build is failing while pushing docker image

Tags: docker, bazel

We are using mono repo and building on master branch which is working for other team members but for me it is failing without proper message.

Error logs:

```
    pushing my_repo/ml/kpi_model_builder/verification_image:latest
/private/var/tmp/_bazel_glod/0f459a477f1aff71444c623d34208101/execroot/tm_repo/bazel-out/darwin-fastbuild/bin/ml/model_builder/deployment/allocation-cp-jobs.dev.gitops.runfiles/repo/ml/model_builder/deployment/my_repo-model-builder.push: line 31:  3878 Killed: 9               ${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../io_bazel_rules_docker/container/go/cmd/pusher/darwin_amd64_stripped/pusher --config=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/ml/kpi_model_builder/image.0.config --



file in which it is giving error:

#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Copyright 2017 The Bazel Authors. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

set -eu

function guess_runfiles() {
    if [ -d ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}.runfiles ]; then
        # Runfiles are adjacent to the current script.
        echo "$( cd ${BASH_SOURCE[0]}.runfiles && pwd )"
    else
        # The current script is within some other script's runfiles.
        mydir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
        echo $mydir | sed -e 's|\(.*\.runfiles\)/.*|\1|'
    fi
}

RUNFILES="${PYTHON_RUNFILES:-$(guess_runfiles)}"

${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../io_bazel_rules_docker/container/go/cmd/pusher/darwin_amd64_stripped/pusher --config=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/ml/model_builder/image.0.config --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/000.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/000.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/000.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/000.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/001.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/001.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/001.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/001.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/002.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/002.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/002.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/002.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/003.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/003.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/003.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/003.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/004.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/004.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/004.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/004.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/005.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/005.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/005.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/005.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/006.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/006.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/006.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/006.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/007.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/007.tar.gz.nogz,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/007.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/../ml_python_vw/image/007.tar.gz.nogz.sha256 --layer=${RUNFILES}/repo/ml/model_builder/image-layer.tar.gz,${RUNFILES}/repo/ml/model_builder/image-layer.tar,${RUNFILES}/repo/ml/model_builder/image-layer.tar.gz.sha256,${RUNFILES}/tm_repo/ml/kpi_model_builder/image-layer.tar.sha256 --manifest=${RUNFILES}/repo/ml/model_builder/image.0.manifest --format=Docker --dst=my_repo.info/ml/model_builder/image:latest "$@"
```

Comment: can you share `bazel command ` and build file?